# How to configure SeriLog ExpressionTemplate in AppSettings.Json

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm trying to implement [Serilog Expression Template](https://nblumhardt.com/2021/06/customize-serilog-text-output/) to Log our application Logs in **Json** format in a FILE (not in Console). I'm unable to find the way to configure the **template** in AppSettings.json.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
    "{{ TimeStamp: @t, Level: @l, Message: @m }}", theme: TemplateTheme.Code))
.CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, in a WriteTo section in the AppSettings.json.

```
"WriteTo": [
    {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
            "Path": "log.txt",
            "Formatter": {
                "Type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
                "Template": "[{@t:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}\n"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a way, but you can try add your logging template as a custom config parameter using IOptions interface and configuration builder

Comment: Reference please

Comment: [This link](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) can be useful, just move configuration builder from startup to program.cs (if it contains serilog configuration)